# Развернуть ImageView в полный экран при нажатии и свернуть обратно при повторном нажатии

Tags: android

у меня есть активити с девятью imageview. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на одно из них, оно открывалось во весь экран? А при повторном нажатии стягивалось обратно?
Нужно создавать новое активити с imageview на весь экран, и как-то вызывать в нем ресурс того imageview, на которое нажали?
Как это проще сделать? Желательно, без использования сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Источник](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/zoom.html), оч хороший хороший пример от Гугла.

Класс, в котором инициализируется требуемое изображение:

```
public class ZoomActivity extends FragmentActivity {    
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
        thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });

        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    }
}
```

Метод для увеличения изображения:

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {    
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
        R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container)
            .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
        > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
        startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(ObjectAnimator
                        .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,    startBounds.left))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.Y,startBounds.top))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
        }
    });
}
```

`thumbnail` - исходное изображение, `imageResId` - картинка, которая будет видна в итоге (увеличенная).

Метод можно/нужно обработать напильником под собственные нужды. Например, я убирал альфу (чтобы исходное изображение не исчезало) и задавал положение (через `finalBounds.top/right/bottom/left`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/78280)

Comment: согласен с вами)